# ASP.NET Identity – UserManager and UserStore issues with non-string user ID

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I managed to successfully convert my codebase to be consistent and use `long` as an ID for every model, including my `User:IdentityUser<long>`. Everything seems to have been working.

That is, until I needed to get the currently logged-in user with `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` and fell down a rabbit hole of hardcoded `string`s everywhere. Quite a big chunk of my initial switch to `long` was made easier thanks to generics, but it seems they're a foreign concept in `UserManager` and `UserStore`.

So far, the only solutions I managed to find were 2013 answers from Stack Overflow that were either horribly outdated or horribly outdated and would require me to essentially copy-paste half the Identity and replace all `string` with `long`, to also hardcode them.

There has to be a better, cleaner way, but I fail to see it.

---

It all started [here](https://github.com/Atulin/Ogma/blob/master/Ogma3/Api/VotesController.cs#L48), which led me to [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/605c522fa3e875fd6d3aefa783a71d1745b7e4c7/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L436), to [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/605c522fa3e875fd6d3aefa783a71d1745b7e4c7/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L532), and eventually to [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IUserStore.cs#L90), at which point the trail stops.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was somewhere else in the code, namely one of the models wasn't updated to store user ID as a `long` and had a `string` property. Changing that, fixed the issue, both `UserManager` and `IUserStore` function properly.